# Hide element when precedent input is empty and not focused

Tags: css, postcss

Is it possible using CSS/PostCSS (magic) to show subsequent element only if the target input is focused and not empty?

I've achived half way to show it when input is focused, but can't figure out yet if it's a thing to combine focus and empty together?

```css
input:not(:focus) + button {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

input:not(:focus):not(:empty) + .notEmptyCase {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Button gets visible when input is focused</p>
<input placeholder="Search">
<button>CLEAR</button>

<p>Button gets visible when input is focused and isn't empty</p>
<input placeholder="Search">
<button class='notEmptyCase'>CLEAR</button>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible with CSS as `:empty` essentially means that the element has "no children" and an `input` cannot have children so it will always apply- *The :empty CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children.*

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/check-empty-input-css

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089405/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually **@Paulie_D is right, you can't use [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class to achieve this**, but this is not impossible with CSS, however, it is very tricky to do. **You should use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) [`(:valid)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) or [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-class** to achieve such a thing, so for using this you also need to make your `input` required (This is for sure). Then when you use this pseudo-class there is no need to check if the input is focused or not in your particular case.

```css
input:not(:focus) + button {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

input:invalid + .notEmptyCase {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Button gets visible when input is focused and isn't empty</p>
<input placeholder="Search">
<button class='notEmptyCase'>CLEAR</button>

<p>Button gets visible when input is focused and isn't empty</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" required>
<button class='notEmptyCase'>CLEAR</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this works like a charm. I had a look on article @Paulie_D shared and there is a hint to use `:placeholder-shown` might also work in combination with :not focus :-)